# How to adjust VBA for formula use?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My apologies up front if this post contains too much information.  I am new to VBA and this site.

After some difficulties trying to run a Macro I recorded, I have tried to break it up into smaller portions. One of those portions includes appending two columns of data, which will then be used to create a table.  The data in these columns is coming from two other worksheets in the same workbook.

When the data is transferred directly by me, the shortened Macro works fine.  However, when I use a formula to transfer the data, the Macro does not work.  I would appreciate suggestions on how to edit the shortened Macro to either adjust for the formula or edit the VBA to transfer the data and then append, so I might then proceed with attempting to create the table.  The code I have been using is:

```
Dim col As Range, _
    found As Range
    Dim currRow As Integer

    currRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("", after:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row

    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
      If col.Column <> 1 Then
        Set found = col.EntireColumn.Find("", after:=col.Cells(1, 1), lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        Set found = ActiveSheet.Range(col.Cells(1, 1), found)
        found.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, 1).PasteSpecial
        currRow = currRow + found.Cells.Count - 1
      End If
    Next col
    
End Sub
```

I should have mentioned the columns of data being copied to the worksheet will have headers and vary in the number of rows from workbook to workbook.  I will try to attach images of the start and desired endpoints.

*The formulas are applied to 200 rows in each column.  When I use the Macro on the data copied using the formula, it seems to append the 200 cells of formula from column 2 to the 200 cells of formula in column 1.  The data stays in each column, and after my last data point in column 1 I now have blank cells down to row 400 that have the formula instead of data.*

[BEginning View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCdXo.jpg)

[Possible Append Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBaBO.jpg)

[Possible Append result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phpxf.jpg)

Comment: A tip for `currRow` : You can rewrite your line as `currRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` but the better way to find the last row of a column is actually to start at the bottom and move upwards, this prevents blank cells in the middle from causing you to wrongly assume you've reached the end. `currRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Rows(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the macro does not work"? Do you have an error? Is the output not as desired? Please describe in more detail what you are having trouble with.

Comment: As is, the code you have posted is saying "On the active worksheet, take all the data in every column and paste a copy of it under the first column's data.". I am not sure that this matches up with your described goal of "appending two columns of data". Can you give an example of what the correct output would look like?

Comment: *when I use a formula to transfer the data the Macro does not work* - please take a moment to [edit] to clarify exactly what happens, and what doesn't. That said `Range.Find` should always be invoked with all the optional parameters specified explicitly, lest you get whatever the user did in Excel's search prompt =)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I will try to apply tips received thus far.  I am still trying to understand the terminology.

Comment: Please let me know if the photos submitted are not helpful in clarifying my goal.